# Temp Files Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, temporary-files

Is it possilbe to create temp files and images in asp.net applications using something like this:

If no, how can i do it? 
(ImagePB is a previously treated Bitmap)

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"img" + imgID.ToString() + "PB" + extencao) == true)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"img" + imgID.ToString() + "PB" + extencao);
        imagePB.Save(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"img" + imgID.ToString() + "PB" + extencao, imgFormat);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Considering this is a .net site, the user the application is executing under will need read/write access to the temp directory.  If you need help setting that up, go to serverfault.com

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `GetTempPath()` should return a temporary file path, and the code you have posted *should* work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx has more information about how `GetTempPath()` get's the path.

Though, it does not verify if the Temp Path directory exists, or is writeable by the application. I haven't run into a situation where `GetTempPath()` does return an inaccessible path. You'd probably want to account for this in your application to handle this situation.

Also be mindful, this is very possibly `C:\Windows\Temp`. It could have limited disk space, or deleted at any time by someone else when disk space is needed. You may want to create a temp path within your application, and delete it when you no longer need it.

Comment: And what about the security problems?

Comment: What type of security problems? Are you worried about someone unauthorized seeing the files? The possibility that you can't write to the folder `GetTempPath()` returns?

Comment: ASP.net applications cannot write to that folder by default.